# Is there a way to make a bind mount for a single container?

Tags: docker

I am have made a Docker container for my Ruby project. I want to have a bind mount for my project files but I can't seem to figure it out.
I usually use docker-compose and I would just include the volume service there and it would work fine.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2

# throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install

COPY . .

CMD ["./script.rb"]
```

As it stands right now I have to rebuild my image every time I add new code and then change the path in the `CMD` line. Obviously, this is bad.

I read the official [docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/06_bind_mounts/) but in there it just shows a huge command line entry which is not ideal either.

Is there a way to have a bind mount and have the container run the code from various folders in my project?

Comment: `CMD` can be replaced in `docker run` command or in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: I gave up on this idea because it seemed like a hustle to make it run =(

Comment: It's actually the easiest way to customize an image. You just `docker run someimage ./script.rb /foo/bar`. For docker-compose you just use `command: "./script.rb /foo/bar"` key and that's it. No need to rebuild the image, just restart the thing.

Comment: I had to run this huge command `docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp/1.0-calculator -w /usr/src/myapp/1.0-calculator ruby-cuce cucumber` and rebuild image everytime I updated code. It just wasnt worth it for me. I will try rvm now.
Thanks for your answers though =)

Comment: Rebuilding your application when you change it is pretty normal (not just in Docker but also in languages like C, Java, Go, ...).  Even if you're deploying via Docker eventually you can use a local rbenv/rvm environment for development and rspec tests.